# How do I strip only the string part from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list that looks like:

```
{
    'J2EE': 0.0202219636,
    'financial': 0.2439565346,
    'Guru': 0.0202219636,
    'AWS': 0.0202219636,
    'next generation': 0.12072663160000001,
    'Machine Learning': 0.2025762767,
    'technology': 0.066936981
}
```

How do I extract only the text parts and make my list look like:

```
['J2EE', 'financial', 'Guru', 'AWS', ...]
```

Should I use Regular expressions?

Comment: A) not a list, it's a dictionary. B) what have you tried?

Comment: Re: regexps - absolutely not!

Comment: I am new to Python, also, I mistook dictionary to be a list. Sorry. I could not figure out anything.

Comment: Sometimes the stackoverflow community can be a bit unwelcoming to newcomers. Don't get discouraged, you'll get a lot of great answers if you follow the community guidelines for asking questions.

Comment: @PrabodhM Thank you, that helped.

Answer (score 5):

What you have there is a dictionary, not a list, and what you want are the keys:

```
your_dict = {'J2EE': 0.0202219636, 'financial': 0.2439565346, 'Guru': 0.0202219636, 'AWS': 0.0202219636, 'next generation': 0.12072663160000001, 'Machine Learning': 0.2025762767, 'technology': 0.066936981}
your_dict_keys = your_dict.keys()
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it, but if you really want it in the form of `{'J2EE','financial','Guru','AWS',....}` use `set(dict)`

Comment: This `set` is quite unnecessary. Dictionary keys are already unique. Simpler to use `dict.keys()`.

Comment: True, but OP specified the output to be a set. Although probably by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As noticed by brittenb in his comment, the data structure in your example is in fact a type we call a dictionary in Python. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries for further details.

Getting the list of keys of a dictionary is done by calling

```
list(dict.keys())
```

This is what calling it on your example would look like:

```
test = {'J2EE': 0.0202219636, 'financial': 0.2439565346, 'Guru': 0.0202219636, 'AWS': 0.0202219636, 'next generation': 0.12072663160000001, 'Machine Learning': 0.2025762767, 'technology': 0.066936981}
list(test.keys())
>>>['financial', 'next generation', 'Guru', 'technology', 'J2EE', 'Machine Learning', 'AWS']
```

Comment: Good approach, but `list()` call is unnecessary here, since `dict.keys()` already returns a list.

Comment: In python 3 it returns a dict_keys class object. test.keys().__class__
<class 'dict_keys'>

Comment: You're right, I'm using Python2. Forgot about this difference.